# What does the special variable $#_ mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I encountered this special variable (`$#_`) while browsing. Tried finding out what it means, but couldn't find any. Please let me know what this special variable mean.

Comment: Did you mean `$_` ?

If so, please see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant "$#_" and not $_.

Comment: When you want to know about some code, show us the code. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Perl, you get the index of the last element of `@array` with the syntax [`$#array`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).  So `$#_` is the index of the last element in the array [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARG).  This is not the same thing as the number of elements in the array (which you get with `scalar @array`), because Perl arrays are normally 0-based.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `$#{ $_ }` is a synonym of `$#_`

Comment: @Zaid, No it's not. `$#_` or (`$#{ _ }`) gets the index of the last element in `@_`. `$#{ $_ }` gets the index of the last element in the array referenced by `$_`.